# Can't install Bower packages in Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, jquery-ui, asp.net-core, bower

I have Visual Studio 2015 with Update 3. I have created new Asp.Net Core Web Application (.NET Core). Then, when I'm trying to install *jquery-ui* with the help of Bower, I get following error:

> ECONNREFUSED Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/jquery-ui
>   failed: connect ECONNREFUSED 23.23.73.170:443

How can I install it, what should I do with this error?

Comment: https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/jquery-ui is live. Are you sure your https port is open?

Comment: I am not sure, how can I check it? And I use proxy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error messages states that nuget cannot open a connection  to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/jquery-ui. You can try to open this URL in your browser. In Chrome this JSON response will be returned:

```
{
    "name": "jquery-ui",
    "url": "https://github.com/components/jqueryui.git"
}
```

Probably this works because the proxy configuration in your browser is already set.

Please check and set the proxy settings of nuget on your machine:
https://docs.nuget.org/consume/nuget-config-settings#proxy-settings

Comment: Where should I find username and password for proxy? I only have server and port.

Comment: Please check this article as well: http://skolima.blogspot.de/2012/07/nuget-proxy-settings.html - I do not know if your proxy requires username and password; you can try to provide only the server and port and see if this works for you.